# Renaming files using the parent folder/directory name as a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that will rename all the documents in all sub-folder with the parent folder name and then the original file name.  For example:

There are 200 folders with unique 4 digit names, all the folders contain a folder called "Data Sheets".  I would like to rename all the documents in the Data Sheets folder to include the 4 digit unique id name.  So essentially I want the documents to be renamed from data sheet.doc to 1234 data sheet.doc

There are many batch scripts out there that do something very close to what I am trying to do but I have been unable to modify them to do exactly what I need.  Any help would be appreciated. This is what I have been trying of similar versions trying to get it to work.

```
@echo off 
for /r %%a in ("S:\Fiscal Yr. 2015\*\*.doc") do ( 
for /d %%d in (%CD%) do ( 
set newname=%%~nd%~x1 
ren "%%~a" "!newname!%%~Xa" 
echo media file in %%~fa renamed to "!newname!%%~Xa" 
) 
)
```

Zach

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24809805/edit). Don't put code in a comment, it is unreadable.

Comment: Not sure why there are 4 votes to close the question, citing 'too broad'.  Seems pretty specific to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify - this will process every `.doc` file in any folder called "Data Sheets" and rename the files to add `the parent folder-name to "Data Sheets"` to the start of the `.doc` files.

This will echo the rename command for you to confirm that it is correct, before removing the first `echo` statement.

```
@echo off 
for /r "S:\Fiscal Yr. 2015" %%a in (*.doc) do (
   for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~pa\.") do (
      if /i "%%~nxb"=="Data Sheets" for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%~pb\.") do (
         echo ren "%%a" "%%~nxc %%~nxa" 
         echo media file "%%a" renamed to "%%~nxc %%~nxa"
      )
   ) 
) 
pause
```

Comment: when I remove echo from 'echo ren "%%a" "%%~nxc %%a"' and run the bat I get "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Try the edited code now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how you can rename all files in an entire folder structure, including all sub-folders:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d "S:\Fiscal Yr. 2015"
set _cd=%CD%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.doc /a-d /s /b') do (
  set old_fn=%%~fni
  set new_fn=!old_fn:%_cd%\=!
  set new_fn=!new_fn:Data Sheets\=!
  set new_fn=!new_fn:\= !
  echo ren "!old_fn!" "!new_fn!"
)

endlocal
```

The `for` command enumerates all the .doc files in in the current folder and sub-folders (`\s` switch).  The `\b` switch makes it output the filenames using `bare` format (which in this case includes the full path).  The `/a-d` makes it ignore directories, so only files get renamed.

Using `setlocal / endlocal` makes it possible to use delayed expansion of variables, and thus we use `!` instead of `%` with the `set` commands.  Delayed expansion ensures that the variables are reevaluated when they are used, instead of using the original value assigned to them.

The `echo ren ...` makes it echo the rename commands to the console instead of actually performing the renames.  You'll want to verify it outputs the right rename statements before you run it for real, and it would be a good idea to backup the folder structure before you do it for real since there is no **undo** for this type of operation.

The batch file removes the leading path and only keeps the sub-folder's name, adding it before the filename, also removing the *Data Sheets* folder name from the new filename.

Comment: James when running this it is renaming all the .doc to the parent folder subfolder and document name.  For example the folder structure is 1234\Data Sheets\Vehicle Info.doc.  After running this the Vehicle Info.doc is being renamed to "1234 Data Sheets Vehicle Info.doc".  How might I go about editing your code so that the name is only changed to "1234 Vehicle Info.doc" so it ignores all the Data Sheet folder names?

Comment: Did you grab the code before my last edit, which removes "Data Sheets\" from "new_fn"?

Comment: I must have, this works perfectly.  Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated.  Best regards!